# Python for Text migrating from 2.79 to 2.8

Tags: python, scripting

I have a Python script that changes the text in a blend. In 2.79 the script is:

```
s = bpy.context.scene
sed = s.sequence_editor
sequences = sed.sequences
f = s.objects['Text']
f.data.body = "New text in the field."
```

"Text" is the name of the field.
This works great.

However, in 2.8 I can use Add Text to do the job of placing the text. However, when I try using the above code, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/proj004/proj004master.py", line 27, in <module>
    f = s.objects['Text']
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Text" not found'
```

I am assuming that since I used Add Text I need to use something other than:

```
s = bpy.context.scene
sed = s.sequence_editor
sequences = sed.sequences
```

Does anybody know how I can make this work?

Comment: `s.objects["Text"]` is a text object linked to the scene.  Since in 2.8 you are using a text strip in VSE ( I assume) there is no font object in scene named "Text", hence the keyerror.  So do something other than that.

Comment: Are you saying there is no way to modify the contents of a text strip using a python script?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be stupid simple:

```
bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all["Test"].text = "New text in the field."
```